# How to find a specific link in the one of a hidden rows of the table strictly by linkText/linkName (without using css-selectors or xpath)?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, css, selenium-webdriver

HTML: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S4tA.jpg

Each "tr" is a row of the table. 
Each row expands a one more hidden row by click.
Each hidden row contains links.
Need to find specific link by linkText, because row are changing every time (id changing too), and link can be found on different rows in different moment of the time. Can't use xpath.

I tried  JavascriptExecutor with script:

```
 arguments[0].click()
```

But it can't execute by linkText without using xpath or css-selector.
And one more problem: I don't know how to restrict execution in the specific table (page could has one more link with the same name).

I tried to create a collection:

```
   WebElement table = $("table locator");
    List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

    for(int i=1;i<allRows.size();i++) {

        WebElement table1 = $("table locator");
        List<WebElement> allRows1 = table1.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    allRows1.get(i).findElement(By.linkText("linkText"));
```

but don't know how to create a collection of hidden elements.

Any idea, how can't i find a hidden link strictly by linkText?
Is it possible to iterate DOM by linkName without an absolute path?
Or the only way is a loop, clicking to each row until the link will be found?

PS: sorry for poor English.

Comment: So, you want to iterate through `tr` which contains hidden `tr` which contains `a` (link) element and then click it? Do you know the name of the desired link?

Comment: can you be more clear and specific ?

Comment: @ Rafał Laskowski: yes, i know the name of the desired link, but don't know in which of hidden rows is it.

Comment: @Elistrago Can't you just find the desired link by linkText? Without iterating over `tr` elements?

Comment: @ Rafał Laskowski: How? The link is hidden until the row has changed style="display:none" to style="display: table-row;"

Comment: @Elistrago You say you can't use Xpath or CSS. Why?

Comment: @Rafał Laskowski: https://imgur.com/a/KUz2c 
CSS could change, Xpath too.

Comment: @Elistrago I still can't see a reason why. 
What elements do you need to click? `tr` with `style="display:none"` ?

Comment: @Elistrago Dynamic elements are not the reason why you can't use CSS or Xpath. There are still valid attributes to use.

Comment: @Elistrago Does desire link exist on the page? Or is it added after you click table row? Is it in the HTML Source from the very beginning?

Comment: @Rafał Laskowski It's possible to execute and click hidden link by Xpath:
        WebElement element = $(By.xpath("//a[text()='linkText']"));
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) getWebDriver();
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element); 
but how can i strict the execution inside  specific CSS (for example: table id) by creating some kind of ElementCollection?

Comment: @Elistrago Check out my answer and let's work on it together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 ways to do it.

1. Iterate through visible `tr` elements
2. Iterate through hidden `tr` elements
3. If link exists in the source code since the beginning, you can find it and it's relevant parent element (row)

Solution #1:

```
WebElement table = $("table locator");
List<WebElement> dataRows = table.findElements(By.cssSelector("tr[class*='data-row']"));
for (int i = 0; i < dataRows.size(); i++) {
     WebElement singleDataRow = dataRows.get(i);
     singleDataRow.click();
}
//all VISIBLE tr elements were clicked. Time to find our link
WebElement link = table.findElement(By.linkText("linkText"));
link.click();
```

Solution #2:

```
WebElement table = $("table locator");
List<WebElement> dataRows = table.findElements(By.cssSelector("tr[class*='actions']"));
for (int i = 0; i < dataRows.size(); i++) {
    WebElement singleDataRow = dataRows.get(i);
    singleDataRow.click();
}
//all HIDDEN tr elements were clicked. Time to find our link
WebElement link = table.findElement(By.linkText("linkText"));
link.click();
```

Solution #3:

```
WebElement link = table.findElement(By.linkText("linkText"));
WebElement parentElementOfLink = link.findElement(By.xpath("./*"));
//this is probably our tr element
parentElementOfLink.click(); //clicks desired row
```

EDIT:

EXTENDED Solution #1:

```
WebElement table = $("table locator");
List<WebElement> dataRows = table.findElements(By.cssSelector("tr[class*='data-row']"));
for (int i = 0; i < dataRows.size(); i++) {
     WebElement singleDataRow = dataRows.get(i);
     singleDataRow.click();

     //we need to find the link after clicking each `tr` element.
     try {
         WebElement link = table.findElement(By.linkText("linkText"));
         link.click();
         break;
     } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
         //ignore the exception. It means our link does not exist in this row and we need to continue the iteration
     }
}
```

Comment: #1 works fine. I'm thinking about the same solution. But one more question: How can i break the iteration as soon as link were found? I need it, because when the next row expand, the previous one collapse.

Comment: @Elistrago I edited my answer. Added Extended Solution :)
Please, accept my answer if it's helpful.

Comment: @ Rafał Laskowski Thank you

Comment: @Elistrago You're welcome :) Happy coding and see you on StackOverflow! Don't hesitate to ask questions if you are stuck :)